# Xml parsing problem

Tags: java, xml

I'm getting some text from an xml file

```
URL url_Twitter = new URL("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timelineID_PROVA.rss"); 
HttpURLConnection conn_Twitter =(HttpURLConnection)url_Twitter.openConnection();   

DocumentBuilderFactory documentBF_Twitter = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();            
DocumentBuilder documentB_Twitter = documentBF_Twitter.newDocumentBuilder();    
Document document_Twitter = documentB_Twitter.parse( conn_Twitter.getInputStream());
```

in the xml there are some characters like &# 8217; so when I call

```
document_Twitter.getElementsByTagName("title").item(2).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()
```

the string are trunked before that kind of characters

The text is in just one tag

```
  <item>
    <title>SMWRME: Internet per &#8220;Collaborare senza confini&#8221;. Soprattutto alla SMW di Roma, dal 7 all'11 febbraio. Ecco il terzo percorso. http://cot.ag/ewnJ4F</title>
    <description>SMWRME: Internet per &#8220;Collaborare senza confini&#8221;. Soprattutto alla SMW di Roma, dal 7 all'11 febbraio. Ecco il terzo percorso. http://cot.ag/ewnJ4F</description>
    <pubDate>Mon, 27 Dec 2010 20:05:01 +0000</pubDate>
    <guid>http://twitter.com/SMWRME/statuses/19483914259140609</guid>
    <link>http://twitter.com/SMWRME/statuses/19483914259140609</link>
    <twitter:source>&lt;a href=&quot;http://cotweet.com/?utm_source=sp1&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;CoTweet&lt;/a&gt;</twitter:source>
    <twitter:place/>
  </item>
```

I noticed that this behavior does happen just for android application.
The same code works fine for a java application.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `document_Twitter.getElementsByTagName("title").item(2).getTextContent()` instead? There might actually be multiple text nodes beneath this node, like

```
- "item" element
  - "title" element
    - text node "SMWRME: Internet per "
    - text node "&#8220;"
    - text node "Collaborare senza confini"
    - text node "&#8221;"
```

Most SAX parsers would deliver the character content split in multiple parts so I can imagine a DOM parser to do the same.
The method [getTextContent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) should return the text content of all sub sub nodes concatenated.

You could also try to call [setCoalescing(true)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setCoalescing%28boolean%29) on your DocumentBuilderFactory before creating the DocumentBuilder, the documentation mentions that this affects CDATA sections but it might also change the handling of character entities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I checked the xml file

Comment: @alessandro In your example xml, the title node does not have a child node, it has only text content.  The getFirstChild call should return null for the title node.